# How to make ssh fail if port forwarding fails

Tags: linux, ssh, solaris, ssh-tunnel

I have a bash script that runs ssh to create a port forward, using a command like this:

```
ssh -N -i keyfile -L 1000:localhost:22 *remote_ip*
```

There are occasions where the listen port may be busy, so this command gives the error:

```
channel_setup_fwd_listener: cannot listen to port: 1000
Could not request local forwarding.
```

However, the ssh connection remains up and the ssh command blocks.  How can I make ssh actually fail when this occurs, so my script can handle it?

Unfortunately, I also need to support this on Solaris (Intel), and the ssh command there doesn't support the ExitOnForwardFailure option - any ideas in this case?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you check the ssh man page, you'll find there is a config option called ExitOnForwardFailure and you can specify it on the command line by adding:

`-o "ExitOnForwardFailure yes"`

All the ssh config options are described in the ssh_config and sshd_config man pages. If you find the option is not supported, you may have to upgrade to a newer version of ssh.

Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks, that wasn't in the man page I googled, but is available to my ssh.

Comment: Does this option really work? I still have a "warning: remote port forwarding failed" and an established connection...

Comment: It seems it doesn't fail it it can bind one port even if another port fails: securityfocus.com/archive/121/505298/30/480/threaded

Answer (score 3):

You can also add `ExitOnForwardFailure yes`
into your `'~/.ssh/config'` file.

Create one if you haven't got one.

Make sure the correct user owns the file.

Restart your ssh service `sudo service ssh restart` on unbuntu.

Comment: `sudo service ssh restart` is about restarting ssh daemon and has nothing to do with ssh client configuration which is stored in `$HOME/.ssh/config`.

Answer (score 0):

Only ExitOnForwardFailure may not enough.

Try use
`-o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes`, `-o ServerAliveInterval=10` and `-o ServerAliveCountMax=3` to make a stable fail.

For example, to remote forward `psql` and `ssh`:

```bash
ssh -NC -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes \
-o ServerAliveInterval=10 \
-o ServerAliveCountMax=3 \
-R remote_dev_ip:5432:127.0.0.1:5432 \
-R remote_dev_ip:2222:127.0.0.1:22 \
tun@remote_dev
```

[Reference](https://medium.com/@souri.rv/autossh-for-keeping-ssh-tunnels-alive-5c14207c6ba9)